# chai - test api - validate multiple statuses

Tags: node.js, api, express, mocha.js, chai

My api has three expected statuses (200, 401, 403) anyone of them can pass the test.
If identified a status other than the listed above must fail the test.

I could find chai validating only one status in a unit test (like below)

```
res.should.have.status(200)
```

```html
res.should.have.status(200)
```

But I'm expecting a statement like below or any other equivalent.

```html
res.should.have.status([200, 401, 403]);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the status is one of the expected ones with help of the regular chai `expect`:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
expect(res.status).to.be.oneOf([200, 401, 403]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is quite rare to check for several status codes in a single test, because a test is simply an atomic use case you're running over your application expecting an specific output, my approach here would be to create a suite for the use case and 3 different test cases for testing each scenario where you can receive any of those status codes (and maybe an specific payload).

Bests of lucks.